# How to convert aspx behind to API controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, migration

I have aspx pages in my application, as a part of the application migration we need to move the code behind of the aspx pages into API controller methods. Instead of going a manual route to convert this, is there a better strategy that can we follow, or any tool is available which can minimize this effort of converting the code behind code into API controller methods.

Comment: There is not one-to-one translation possible between web forms to MVC controllers. They are entirely different...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.